# $\exp\left(\sum_{j>s} \log(1+a_j) \right)-1\leq C\sum_{j>s}a_j$ for some constant $C>0$?

Tags: inequality

My question is if the inequality below is true:
$$\exp\left(\sum_{j>s} \log(1+a_j) \right)-1\leq C\sum_{j>s}a_j$$
for some constant $C>0$.

This inequality is from the equation (12) in the page 8 of [this paper](https://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/sam_reports/reports_final/reports2017/2017-03_rev1.pdf).

There are some given condition on the sequence $a_j$ in that paper but it seems to me that the condition does not matter for this inequality. For now...although it looks easy... I cannot come up with any idea...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have $n$ terms $a_j$ which are all equal to $a$ then the inequality becomes $(1+a)^n \le 1+Cn a$, and that does not hold for arbitrary $a$ or $n$. So *some* restriction on the $a_j$ may be required.

Comment: Because $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$, the left hand side may be rewritten as $\left( \prod (1+a_j) \right) -1$.  Without some conditions on the $a_j$, this feels false.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but in that paper, $(\sqrt{a_j})\in\ell^p$ and $a_j<1$ and it seems to me that $C$ is allowed to depend on this sequence but wanted to be independent of $s.$

Comment: @Aaron,  I am sorry. I did not mentioned that the series converges. Then it should have no problem.. I guess....

Comment: Afterthought of my previous comment: we even have, $(a_j)\in\ell^1$, and this is sufficient for  $C$ (depending on this sequence) to be independent of $s.$

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the proof!

The key was the fundamental inequality $\log(x)\leq x-1$.

Observe that, since exponential function is monotonically increasing,
\begin{equation}
\exp\left( \sum_{j>s}\log(1+a_j)  \right) -1\leq \exp\left(\sum_{j>s} a_j \right)-1 \leq \sum_{j>s}a_j \left( 1+ \frac{a}{2!}+\frac{a^2}{3!}+\cdots  \right)\leq \sum_{j>s}a_j e^a
\end{equation}
where  $a=\sum_{j\geq 1}a_j<\infty$. So considering $e^a=C$, we are done. Thank you all!

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Your factor factor $C$ depends on the $a_j$.

Comment: @MartinR  I am sorry. I think I was not super clear.  In the paper, we are only interested in the convergence with respect to $s\rightarrow \infty$. Thus, as long as C is independent, we are fine.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you ! I just edited

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry.. but why $1/a$?

Comment: @AnneBauval   Oh I see you are more precise.  But $e^a$ is fine as well.  I just multiplied 2 to second, 3 to third terms and so on.

Comment: Oh yes fine, $\frac{e^a-1}a\le e^a.$